# Derivation of the oil drop experiment

Tags: homework-and-exercises, experimental-physics

The oil drop experiment performed by Robert Millikan in 1909 enables us to calculate the elementary charge.

The following forces have effect on the droplet:

1. $F_\mathrm{G} = m g = \frac{4}{3} \, \pi r^3 \rho_\mathrm{Oil} g$
2. $F_\mathrm{A} = \frac{4}{3} \, \pi r^3 \rho_\mathrm{Air} g$
3. $F_\mathrm{E} = q E = \frac{qU}{d}$
4. $F_\mathrm{R} = 6\,\pi\eta r v$

However, which steps of calculation are necessary to finally calculate the elementary electric charge (charge of the electron) or at least a multiple of it?

$$q = \frac{9 \pi d}{2 U} \sqrt{\frac{\eta^3 (v_1 - v_2)}{\rho^* g}} (v_1 + v_2)$$

Comment: Did you  check the wikipedia ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millikan_oil_drop_experiment